# Masturbating to stop prostate cancer

Tags: halacha, sexuality, health-safety-shmira

In Judaism it is forbidden to masturbate ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judaism_and_masturbation)).

[This article](http://www.webmd.com/prostate-cancer/news/20090127/masturbation-and-prostate-cancer-risk) brings two studies; one suggesting that masturbation can cause prostate cancer and another suggesting that it can help prevent it.

In the (hypothetical) case in the future where science has conclusively ruled that masturbation can help prevent cancer, would it then be halachically permitted to masturbate in order to prevent cancer?

Comment: Why would that make it permitted? If pig is found to be high in LDL cholesterol, does that make it permitted?

Comment: Wouldn't ejaculation inside of his wife be equally effective?

Comment: Perhaps, in a specifc case, if a doctor told someone, if you don't masturbate AND accounting for @DoubleAA's last comment, let's say doing that would harm his wife, MAYBE that would be permitted, as he's doing something to prevent ruining his health? Wouldn't that be similar to a doctor recommending eating shark bone b/c that was the BEST (not the only) thing that would prevent worsening someone's osteoporosis?

Comment: @DanF Eating shark bone pills is not an Issur Deoraita. (Nor is it potentially Gilui Arayot which you must die rather than violate.)

Comment: @DoubleAA does anyone say masturbation is in any way gilui arayot? News to me if so.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen I'm not sure but it wouldn't be the craziest opinion out there.

Comment: It may be a good enough reason to allow marrying a second wife.

Comment: @DoubleAA, this question would be the same if (e.g.) it was found "conclusively" that pig caused you to live longer. Also, regarding "ejaculation inside of his wife", this question is obviously speaking hypothetically e.g. what if he has no wife, or what if the doctor 'prescribes' more masturbation than his wife is willing in intercourse? etc.

Comment: @bon if pikuach nefesh demand more sex the wife has little basis for refusing and he has little basis to avoid finding a wife.

Comment: @DoubleAA perhaps the prescription is for ejaculation every day, and his wife is not yet postmenopausal. Masturbation or taking a second wife will both be better than sex during niddah ostensibly.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen I hope you appreciate the absurdity of claiming ejaculating every single day without exception is Pikuach Nefesh. 99% of people don't do that, and they are to be called murders for not caring about Pikuach Nefesh??

Comment: The rambam speaks about this in mishne torah hilchos deot chapter 4. He says that when a man consistently get erections without brininging them upon himself and his body is warm and he feels strong then it is medically adviseable to have relations with his wife (if she ofcourse is permitted to him). But for those that don't have wives what should they do? Searching for a woman just for sex is definitely not the answer. IMO. A man should marry for multiplying because the stresses that come with deep relationships could outweigh the benefits of ejaculating at a "medically adviseable" time.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen IIRC the gemara (niddah 13b) brings a *berayso* that learn the issur of masturbating from "לא תנאף".